# Excel - How can IF function return multiple values in different cells?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

This is what I want: 
If A1 = "Red", return "yes" in the current cell and "good" in A3. And I don't want any code in A3.

Comment: You would need an event macro.

Comment: You can't do that with a single formula. Formulas only return a value to the cell they occupy, unless they are are array (CSE) formulas in which case they return an array of results to the cells they occupy

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(A1="Red", {"yes","good"},"")
```

After entering the formula select the cell and extend the selection to its right side so that the cell with the formula and its adjacent right side cell is also selected

Now press F2; excel will enter in edit mode for the formula cell, now press Ctrl+Shift+ Enter